# Is android:excludeFromRecents broken for the first app that is launched on the device on Android L?

Tags: android

Is seems like the current way to exclude apps from the recent apps-lists in android L is broken. Our app is using android:excludeFromRecents and it works just fine. Unless our app is the FIRST app to start when the device reboots.

This is how it looks when our app is exited as the first app on the device:
[image: InBrowser, with android:excludeFromRecents, started as the first app on device]

And here is how it looks if we first start the camera (or any other app), then our app and exit both:
[image: Camera is started first, then InBrowser. Working as expected.]

Simply put: If an app with android:excludeFromRecents is started as the first app on the device, the directive android:excludeFromRecents isn't working. If another app has been started before the android:excludeFromRecents-app, it works as expected.

Is this a really weird edge-case bug or am i'm missing something very obvious here?

We build a very privacy cautious web browser (http://inbrowserapp.com), so we cannot have any screenshots from the app showing once the app is closed. But this should also affect banking-apps, password-managers etc since sensitive information will be screenshotted if the app is the first to start after a reboot.

Maybe we can go about the route and hide the sensitive information with a blank view when the user is exiting on Android L. But its seems like something is buggy here?

Comment: That definitely seems odd. [An issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=94507) was filed on it a few days ago -- not sure if that was from somebody with your group. You might augment that issue report with what you're seeing, as since your app is available, it should be easier for Google engineers to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, i'll do just that! (Nope, not from our team - but hopefully a google engineer will notice this issue).

Comment: This is working in 5.0 but not in 5.0.1. I don't why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to say that this is fixed for Android 5.1. Just confirmed it on a device running 5.1.

So the correct solution, for us anyways, is to deny screenshots with getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE); for Lollipop with SDK version 21, anything below or above that should be fine.

Comment: I don't know why this is working in 5.0 but not in 5.0.1. Please explain

Comment: @Ajit For us, it was only targetSdkVersion 21 that was affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least prevent the screenshot in recents by setting this flag:
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

But it's still a bug that never should have made it to release..

Comment: I'm going to approve this as the correct answer for now. 

We decided to do FLAG_SECURE on all devices running L until Google rolls out a fix for the broken android:excludeFromRecents.